# Table Data visible below Fixed Table Header while Scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

I am Trying to create a Table with with fixed header, I have created successfully, But While scrolling the table data , table data is visible below to the header, It's overlapping.

Here is the Screenshot:
[image]

If you see while I scrolling the EffectiveStart is scrolling below the header and its visible.

Here is the code:

```
<div id="attributeDifferences" class="table-responsive">
                    <table id="differencesTable" class="table table-striped">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Code</th>
                                <th>Attribute</th>
                                <th>File1</th>
                                <th>File2</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <!-- Rows will be added dynamically  -->
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
```

Css:

```
/* Style for the differences table container */
#attributeDifferences {
    margin-top: 20px;
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    max-height: 500px; /* height of the table*/
    overflow-y: auto;
}

/* Style for table header cells */
#differencesTable th {
    background-color: #6C7AE0;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

/* Style for table data cells */
#differencesTable td {
    padding: 12px;
}

/* Add alternating background color for rows */
#differencesTable tbody tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

#differencesTable tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #F8F6FF;
}

/* Hover effect on table rows */
#differencesTable tbody tr:hover {
    background-color: #E0E0E0;
    transition: background-color 0.2s;
}


/* CSS for responsiveness and styling */
#differencesTable {
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}

#differencesTable th,
#differencesTable td {
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

**Can anyone please help me to resolve this ?**

Comment: I removed the [tag:java] tag as it doesn't seem to have anything to do with the question

Answer (score 0):

The reason your table data is visible even when scrolling is due to the position: sticky property applied to the table header cells. This property ensures that these elements maintain their position relative to the user's scrollbar, which allows them to "stick" to the top of their container. However, the table body rows are not getting hidden when scroll up under the sticky header, and is because the sticky header has transparent background.

So, you need to modify your CSS:-

```
#differencesTable th {
    background-color: #6C7AE0;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    background: #6C7AE0;
}
```

you might also want to add a shadow to create a visual separation between the header, then add this:-

```
#differencesTable th {
    box-shadow: 0 2px 2px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1); 
   }
```

Comment: Its not working, still visible